# Find out if notification was received while app was in background

Tags: cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

When I bring my cordova app to the foreground I want to check if a notification was received, while the app was in the background. **Is there a way to catch pending notifications?** Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?

I started with the following, but it doesnt work:

```
document.addEventListener("resume", resume, false);

function resume(){
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    pushNotification.getPendingNotifications(function(notifications) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(notifications));
    });
};
```

I use this plugin: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin and showing notifications works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) has `getPendingNotifications`. The default plugin behavior is that if it receives notification in background, it will create a notification in status bar. If the user clicks on the notification, the message will be received by your application when it comes to foreground.